# Binary Tree Find number nearest and greater than the key

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Say I have a balanced binary tree. I wish to search for a key k in the tree. However, if k doesn't exist in the binary tree, it should give me the next greatest number nearest to k.

For examples suppose I have these numbers [1,5,6,8,10] as keys in the tree. If I search for '7' it should return 8 and if I search for 2 it should return 5 etc.

What would have to be the modifications in the binary tree to be able to perform such a search? I want an O(log n) solution as well please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean "binary search tree" rather than "binary tree", you don't need any modifications to find the minimum element y in the tree such that y >= x.

```
search(n, x, best_so_far) ::=
    if n == nil { return best_so_far }
    if n.value == x { return x }
    if n.value > x { return search(n.left, x, min(best_so_far, n.value) }
    if n.value < x { return search(n.right, x, best_so_far) }
```

You would call this function as `search(root, x, +infinity)`.

The idea is that if you're exploring the left branch at a node n, you don't need to consider anything to the right of n: n.value is larger than x, and everything to the right is larger than n.value. Similarly, if you're exploring the right branch of a node n, then you can discard everything to the left of n: n.value is smaller than x and everything to the left of n is smaller than n.value.

The code's runtime is bounded by the height of the tree, so is O(log n) if the tree is balanced.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on my other answer, Paul. I sat down and actually thought about the problem instead of winging an answer, and I think the following would be a succinct summary of the solution: "The last node at which you recursed down the left subtree is the answer." This means that there would be need to take the min of best so far and the current node's value. Thoughts?